# Apache proxy_mod refresh

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, mod-proxy

I have an apache web server with a ProxyPass configuration to link a Tomcat server:

```
ProxyPass /server http://localhost:8080/server
ProxyPassReverse /server http://localhost:8080/server
```

When Tomcat is down I obviously get a http 305 error. But when Tomcat back up for a few Apache still send 503 without ping Tomcat. I think this due a cache of that proxy because if I wait or restart Apache everythink works again.

How to disable or reduce this cache time?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

append `retry=0` to the ProxyPass directive. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass